# Load data infile into table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I got a table 'IDS_FOR_TEST' with one column 'ID'. I got a properties file which looks like the following (1000 rows):

```
7891047530491120702
3451234346467537818
3145645454491172774
3866378679491223630
4628565630491229555

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C://Users//xxxx//Desktop//filename.properties'
INTO TABLE IDS_FOR_TEST;
```

If I try to execute the above in DbVisualiser I am getting the following not very informative error message:

```
[Error Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]ORA-00900: invalid sql-operation
```

Do you have any idea of what I am doing wrong and how to achieve my goal?

Comment: You can do this with sql developer very simple

Comment: I know, but i need to do this via sql-statements.

Comment: try this: load data
infile 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\filename.properties'
append
into table IDS_FOR_TEST;

Comment: I think 900 error code means invalid statement, your sql commands might not be supported by oracle so you might need to find oracle alternative, might want to take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_concepts.htm#SUTIL003

Comment: There is no SQL statement `load data` in Oracle. Where in the [Oracle manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/toc.htm) did you find that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/load-data.html So there is no way of importing a file into a table per sql?

Comment: That link is for **MySQL** which is something *completely* different than the Oracle database. You should read the manual that applies to the DBMS you are using. To do a bulk load in Oracle you should use SQL*Loader: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/part_ldr.htm#i436326